# Indent a multiline output from an expression to the rest of the template

Tags: playframework, indentation, template-engine

Whenever I have an expression in a scala template that outputs more than one line, it leaves the generated document a bit messy because it is not properly indented.

Is there anyway to workaround this? What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you can do is to  play a little with intends within the Scala parts of templates (i.e. loops) if it's annoying you, anyway most probably this will be waste of time. Actually "ugly" formatting of HTML hasn't any side-effects for working of the page as every browser can handle the code fine nevertheless if it is intended *correctly* or not.

If you still not convicted you can use some external libraries, i.e. [**HtmlCompressor**](https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/) (best for minimalizing transfer rates on paid plans) like:

```java
public Result compressor(){
    String html = ugly.render("hi there").toString();
    HtmlCompressor compressor = new HtmlCompressor();
    return ok(compressor.compress(html)).as("text/html; charset=utf-8");
}
```

Or [**Jsoup**](http://jsoup.org/) (BTW: it's much more than just *code cleaner*)

```java
public Result jsoup(){
    String html = ugly.render("hi there").toString();
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    return ok(doc.outerHtml()).as("text/html; charset=utf-8");
}
```

Of course there are *raw* samples and for easier work you can i.e. override 
`ok(...)` action within your controller.

What's more you will pay some *performance* price for this, so consider using caching where/if possible.

Samples given for Play 2.4 / Java